# How can i access a js value in post response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a jquery post request to obtain a part of the html code from server. There is a file on server get_info.php which prints html code for different requirements. I am using following code to do this :

```
function check(inf_type) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "get_info.php",
        data: { "sequence_no" : 1 },
        success: function(data) {
            // how can i use value of variable "inf_type" here.
            // here, the variable "data" contains HTML code.
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
}
```

the function check() accepts a parameter **inf_type** which contains random strings according to which, server recognize the html code to print. Now, i want handle the POST response according to this **inf_type**.
How can i access the value of **inf_type** variable in POST response function? The function check() is called more often, thats why i can not put the **inf_type** variable value in any global variable.
What can i do to achieve that?
Please guide me. thanks in advance.

Comment: “Closures are poor man's objects”. Learn about `Closures`. I mean in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: Not related to your question, but why a `POST` request to *get* HTML response?

Comment: @NikhilPatil: That is just a filename. I need to send even different and larger data to server through that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it via `inf_type` parameter of the `check()` function:

```
function check(inf_type) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "get_info.php",
        data: { "sequence_no" : 1 },
        success: function(data) {
            if (inf_type == 0) {
                // do something with data
            } else {
                // do something else
            }
        },
        dataType: 'text'
   });
```

}

The reason why this works is because the inner function (success callback) has access to variables in the outer function (check). See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/69868

**Edit**
This assumes that inf_type is a either a number or a new (different) instance of object in each call of `check()`. Details are explained in the link mentioned above.

Comment: inf_type is not a global variable and the check() function is called, lets say, 2 times in a second with 2 different values of inf_type. In this case the requests and values should not be mixed.

Comment: @Forte That's the point! Since inf_type is not a global variable, it is local for the invocation of check() function. Therefore the success callback will use this local value, always the right one. Please do read the link I gave you for longer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the info_type variable in the Success function. scope of parameter info_type is still exists in your success function.

Comment: inf_type is not a global variable and the check() function is called, lets say, 2 times in a second with 2 different values of inf_type. In this case the requests and values should not be mixed.

Comment: No it wont be mixed.For each function call info_type will have its own instance value. You can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the variable in success or in error function.

```
function check(inf_type) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "get_info.php",
        data: { "sequence_no" : 1 },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(inf_type); //inf_type is available here.
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
}
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to send the **inf_type** to the server for the specific values to return like this :

```
function check(inf_type) {
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "get_info.php",
    data: { "sequence_no" : 1, whatToSearch : inf_type }, // i added
    success: function(data) {
         //$(selector).html(data);//where you want to show the data
        // how can i use value of variable "inf_type" here.
        // here, the variable "data" contains HTML code.
    },
    dataType: 'text'
 });
}
```

Comment: because the server is sending HTML code in response, i was looking for another way which is more short and perfect. thank you for your help.

Comment: sending inf_type to server and again taking it back, then searching in response data for the value because its a HTML code patch.. this involves lot of iterations. I just wanted to keep my js codes simple and easily understandable.

Comment: so you every time takes full data from the server and then sorts it out by javascript, why don't you send the **inf_type** in request and pulls data from server which is relevant to it and sets the returned data directly to the respective div or span......